# Как правильно добавить плавность замены отступа блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Есть скрипт липкого блока, который позиционирует блок в зависимости от прокрутки. На странице с ajax навигацией по кнопке, при нажатии на эту кнопку, скрипт позиционирует липкий блок с `position: absolute` на `position: fixed`, и пересчитывает отступ от верха экрана `top: Npx`, и делается это жестко. Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно добавить плавность? Спасибо!

```
ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
var $items = $(items);
$items.each(function() {$('#sticky-box').trigger('update');} );
});
```

Comment: В `css` данному блоку добавь `transition`

Comment: @LADYX дайте более подробный пример кода, проблема может быть практически в чем угодно. Желательно с JSFiddle если возможно.

Comment: ну да, только хотел написать...  покажи код нормально `css html`

Comment: Извини, но я не понял, что и как  там должно куда плавно срабатывать

Comment: Ты про `Крымски опрос` который дергается вниз на пару пикселей?

Comment: Думаю, ни как не придумаю, что посоветовать... покажи просто кусок этого блока  `id="sticky-box" и его css`

Comment: ну тогда попытайся это реализовать, с помощью `jq animation`